# How to use Modulo inside of a forEach loop using arrow function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I just do a coding challenge and I know how to solve it with a classic if-else statement using a forEach loop without arrow functions.

Now I wonder how can I achieve this using ES6 within the forEach loop?

```
// Create a function that returns the product of all odd integers in an array.
const odds = [ 2, 3, 6, 7, 8 ];
const oddProduct = (arr) => {
    arr.forEach(function(element) {
        if (element % 2 === 0) {
            console.log(element);
        }
    });
};

oddProduct(odds);
```

I already learned how to create an arrow function for the forEach loop, but I have no clue how to add in the if-else statement.

```
const oddProduct = (arr) => {
    arr.forEach((element) => console.log(element));
};
```

Also, if someone could tell me the shortest possible way to do this using shorthand statements, I'd be happy to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just change the `function(element) {` to `(element) => {`:

```js
const odds = [ 2, 3, 6, 7, 8 ];
const oddProduct = (arr) => {
    arr.forEach((element) => {
        if (element % 2 === 0) {
            console.log(element);
        }
    });
};

oddProduct(odds);
```

If you *really needed* a concise body without the `{`, you can use `&&` instead, but this is hard to read (I definitely wouldn't recommend it):

```js
const odds = [ 2, 3, 6, 7, 8 ];
const oddProduct = (arr) => {
    arr.forEach(element => element % 2 === 0 && console.log(element))
};

oddProduct(odds);
```

But I'd prefer using `.filter` followed by `forEach` instead:

```js
const odds = [ 2, 3, 6, 7, 8 ];
const oddProduct = (arr) => {
  arr
    .filter(element => element % 2 === 0)
    .forEach(element => console.log(element));
};

oddProduct(odds);
```

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question! So I have to use another => to initiate the next function, got it!

Answer (score 0):

```
const oddProduct = (arr) => {
    arr.forEach((element) => {
       if (element % 2 === 0) {
         console.log(element);
       }
    });
};
```

Shortest possible way

```
const oddProduct = arr => {
      arr.forEach(element => element % 2 === 0 && console.log(element))
 };
```

Another way to do it would be

```
const oddProduct = arr => arr.forEach(e => e%2 && console.log(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do it in  if-else condition, you can do it using filter function that will do magic for you please follow the below following code,

```
const odds = [ 2, 3, 6, 7, 8 ];

const evenValue = odds.filter((value, index, self) => {
  return self.indexOf(value) % 2 == 0;
});

console.log(evenValue)
```

Live Run : https://jsbin.com/qavejof/edit?js,console